# Sum with reciprocal central binomial and harmonic number $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2n}}{n^2 C_{2n}^{n}}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation

I am trying to calculate this sum,and below is my attempt:
$$\displaystyle{S}=\underset{{n}=\mathrm{1}} {\overset{\infty} {\sum}}\frac{{H}_{\mathrm{2}{n}} }{{n}^{\mathrm{2}} \left({C}_{\mathrm{2}{n}} ^{{n}} \right)}=\underset{{n}=\mathrm{1}} {\overset{\infty} {\sum}}\frac{\mathrm{2}}{{n}\left({C}_{\mathrm{2}{n}} ^{{n}} \right)}\left(\frac{{H}_{\mathrm{2}{n}} }{\mathrm{2}{n}}\right)=-\mathrm{2}\underset{{n}=\mathrm{1}} {\overset{\infty} {\sum}}\frac{\mathrm{1}}{{n}\left({C}_{\mathrm{2}{n}} ^{{n}} \right)}\left(\int_{\mathrm{0}} ^{\mathrm{1}} {x}^{\mathrm{2}{n}−\mathrm{1}} \mathrm{ln}\left(\mathrm{1}−{x}\right){dx}\right) \\=−\mathrm{2}\int_{\mathrm{0}} ^{\mathrm{1}} \mathrm{ln}\left(\mathrm{1}−{x}\right){dx}\left(\underset{{n}=\mathrm{1}} {\overset{\infty} {\sum}}\frac{{x}^{\mathrm{2}{n}−\mathrm{1}} }{{n}\left({C}_{\mathrm{2}{n}} ^{{n}} \right)}\right)=−\mathrm{4}\int_{\mathrm{0}} ^{\mathrm{1}} \mathrm{ln}\left(\mathrm{1}−{x}\right)\frac{\mathrm{sin}^{−\mathrm{1}} \left(\frac{{x}}{\mathrm{2}}\right)}{\:\sqrt{\mathrm{4}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }}{dx} \\{x}=\mathrm{2sin}\left({t}\right)\Rightarrow{t}=\mathrm{sin}^{−\mathrm{1}} \left(\frac{{x}}{\mathrm{2}}\right)\Rightarrow{dt}=\frac{{dx}}{\:\sqrt{\mathrm{4}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }} \\\Rightarrow{S}=−\mathrm{4}\int_{\mathrm{0}} ^{\frac{\pi}{\mathrm{6}}} {t}\mathrm{ln}\left(\mathrm{1}−\mathrm{2sin}\left({t}\right)\right){dt} \\ $$
But at this step, I don't know how to process further. Can I ask a hint or another approach? Thank you so much.

Comment: Your calculations are very correct and $(+1)$

Comment: $$S = \frac{17 \zeta (3)}{9}-\frac{\pi  L_{-3}(2)}{\sqrt{3}}$$ here $L_{-3}(s) = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{1}{(3n+1)^s} - \frac{1}{(3n+2)^s}$. You can convert $L_{-3}(2)$ to polygamma / polylog / Hurwitz zeta, whichever you like.

Comment: Thank you @pisco. Can i ask some steps to arrive your result?.

Comment: Thank you @ClaudeLeibovici sir.

Comment: May be you could accepat the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

I did not check your steps, but, if the problem is
$$I=\int t \,\log (1-2 \sin (t))\,dt$$ one integration by parts gives
$$I=\frac{1}{2} t^2\, \log (1-2 \sin (t))+\int \frac{t^2 \cos (t)}{1-2 \sin (t)}\,dt$$ Using Euler representation, let $e^{it}=x$
$$\int\frac{t^2 \cos (t)}{1-2 \sin (t)}\,dt=\frac 12 \int\frac{\left(x^2+1\right) \log ^2(x)}{x \left(x^2-i x-1\right)}\,dx $$
Let $(a,b)$ be the roots of the quadratic
$$\frac {x^2+1}{x(x-a)(x-b)}=\frac{1}{a b x}+\frac{a^2+1}{a (a-b) (x-a)}+\frac{b^2+1}{b (b-a) (x-b)}$$
The first integral is more than simple and what remains are two integrals
$$I(c)=\int \frac{\log ^2(x)}{x-c}\,dx$$ Again,two integrations by parts
$$I(c)=\log ^2(x) \log \left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right)+2 \log (x) \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)-2
   \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)$$

I let you recombining everything, using
$$a=-\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{3}-i\right)\qquad \qquad b=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{3}+i\right)$$ go back to $t$ if you wish and use the bounds.

The result is nice.

Comment: You might want to challenge Mathematica to further simplify the result to the one I commented. But almost surely, MMA can't do it.

Comment: @pisco. I did it and arrived at the result you gave

Answer (score 3):

*Jus to the fun of using once more my favored $1400^=$ years old approximation of the sine function*
$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad \text{for} \qquad 0\leq x\leq\pi$$
$$1-2\sin(t)=\frac{(\pi -6 t) (5 \pi -6 t)}{(2t-(1-2i)\pi)\,(2t-(1+2i)\pi) }$$
Expand the logarithm and the integral is
$$\sim \frac {\pi^2}{18}\left(14\log(3)+6\log(5)-33\log(2)-9 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{7}{24}\right) \right)$$ which is in a relative error of $0.434$%.